# Javascript Click() Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, click

I'm learning Javascript and having trouble.
My HTML:

```
<a id="1" class="same" href="1">click</a>
<a id="1" class="same" href="1">click</a>
<a id="2" class="same" href="1">click</a>
<a id="3" class="same" href="1">click</a>
<a id="3" class="same" href="1">click</a>
<a id="4" class="same" href="1">click</a>
```

And JS:

```
var dataall = [];
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.same');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var id = a[i].id;
    dataall.push(id);
}
data = dataall.filter(function(elem, pos) {
    return dataall.indexOf(elem) == pos;
})
i = 0;
Click(data, i);

function Click(data, i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(data[i]).click();
        if (i < data.length) {
            i++;
            Click(data, i);
        } else {
            alert('done');
        }
    }, 10000)
}
```

How to click each one for an id 1 2 3 4, not 1 1 2 3 3 4?
Thank

Comment: ID needs to be unique.

Comment: `IDs` are supposed to be unique, why do you have multiple `a` tags with the same `ID` in the first place?

Comment: And ids can't start with a number.

Comment: If you're learning JavaScript with this as an example, can I kindly suggest you skip back a chapter or two and consolidate what you already know?

Comment: My code is very long, so I took the above example
I had 6 clicks and clicks may be 4 for 4 id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID need to be unique and can't start with numbers. Still if you want to go with the code.

Try this:

```
    var dataall = [];
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.same');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var id = a[i].id;
    if(dataall.indexOf(id)==-1)
    dataall.push(id);
}
data = dataall.filter(function(elem, pos) {
    return dataall.indexOf(elem) == pos;
})
i = 0;
Click(data, i);

function Click(data, i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (i < data.length) {
             alert("id: "+data[i]);
            document.getElementById(data[i]).click();
            i++;
            Click(data, i);
        } else {
            alert('done');
        }
    }, 100)
}
```

`if(dataall.indexOf(id)==-1)` will check if already id is there in array or not. (duplicate values will not be added).

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xyqYr/2/)**

Comment: it gives alert is accurate
how to get click through id?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I will create a full script
your code works fine, please wait for me for a while
thank you

Comment: i'm sorry, working fine, dataall.indexOf(id)==-1 === data = dataall.filter(function(elem, pos) {
    return dataall.indexOf(elem) == pos;
}), thank you very much